# Use tvOS 12 UITabBarController default UI in tvOS 13 app compiled with Xcode 11

Tags: xcode, uitabbarcontroller, tvos, xcode11, tvos13

tvOS 13 introduces a completely new default UI for `UITabBarController`.

Is it possible to use the default UI of `UITabBarController` that was in previous versions of tvOS, 9-12, in a tvOS 13 application compiled with Xcode 11?

tvOS 9-12 `UITabBarController` (Desired UI):
[image]

tvOS 13 `UITabBarController`:
[image]

Comment: Can you attach sample code or project?

Comment: The main answer - no, you can't do this easily.  This can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58320307/how-to-change-background-color-for-tab-in-tvos-13

Comment: @NikKov yeah I've migrated to adopting the new styling. Was hoping for a temporary solution for this during the transition period.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking abut the "*always on top*" behaviour of the new UI then you can change this by using:

```
var tabBarObservedScrollView: UIScrollView? { get set }
```

Comment: This doesn’t account for hitting the menu button and having the tab bar appear. Using this will scroll to top when menu is pressed.